# Making variables available to all classes, ActionScript 3

Tags: class, actionscript-3, flash, variables, frameworks

I have declared some `variables` inside my fla's document class (`main.as`). I want these `variables` to be accessible to all my program's `classes`.

*In-depth detail:*

The `main.as`-class declares some public `variables`. It then goes on to add a MovieClip-instance called `scene`, which basically works as a container for the rest of my program's content. Lastly it adds some `children` inside of `scene`. These `children`'s classes take over from here.

So the hierarchy is basically like this: `stage`=>`scene`=>`children`.

*The app itself:*

When you open the program you are presented with a list of mini-games. Once you have picked a mini-game, a `child` of that mini-game will be added, i.e. the `child` inside `scene`.

Regardless of what mini-game you picked there is a `scoreboard` system that will determine your points i.e. the `variables`.

Each mini-game will manipulate these points and `scoreboard` conditions in it's own way. These conditions and points (`variables`) are simply declared in `main.as`.

All help appreciated!

Comment: It can't access them exactly. You need to pass those values to new variables in the class using a function.

Comment: How exactly do you want to access those variables in the children? Do you want to read them or write them out both. Please give a concrete example for such a variable.

Comment: @null When you open the app you are presented with a list of mini-games. Once you have picked a mini-game, a `child` of that mini-game will be added, i.e. the `child` inside `scene`.

Regardless of what mini-game you picked there is a `scoreboard` system that will determine your points i.e. the `variables`.

Each mini-game will manipulate these points and `scoreboard` conditions in it's own way.

These conditions and points (`variables`) are simply declared in `main.as`.

Comment: Not sure why someone when on a downvote spree with this question.  The question is fine and there is some valuable info in some of the answers.  If you like to downvote, please be constructive otherwise it is not helpful to anyone (though they'll likely never be back to read this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution that's usually good in general to this problem is: **If an object needs something, this something is passed to it as a parameter.**

> Each mini-game will manipulate these points and `scoreboard` conditions in it's own way. These conditions and points (`variables`) are simply declared in `main.as`.

Your points should not be a basic variable like `int` for example:

```
var points:int = 0;
```

The problem with those is that you cannot pass them by reference. That means you cannot pass them to a game. If you do, a copy is created and the game will only modify its copy.

Instead you should create a class for your points, let's call it `Score`.

```
package
{
    public class Score
    {
        private var _points:int;

        public function Score ()
        {
            _points = 0;
        }

        public function get points():int
        {
            return _points;
        }

        public function set points(value:int)
        {
            _points = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then instantiate a `Score` object in `main.as`:

```
var score:Score = new Score();
```

When you create your games, pass that object to each of your games, for example:

```
var game:Game1 = new Game1(score);
```

Now each game knows the `Score` object and it can manipulate that object. For example each game can do the following with the reference to the object it received via its constructor:

```
score.points += 5;
```

The `Score` class represents the `scoreboard` system.

---

### tl;dr

1. Create a dedicated class that contains all the variables related to scoring and the scoreboard.
2. create an instance of that class in `main.as`
3. pass the instance to each individual game, so that it can manipulate the score

Comment: Seems like a good and logical solution, props for detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

an additional option (assuming previeous answer) is using **static** keyword

a **static** *variable* or *function* will be available any time and any where without defining any instance of that class which they'r defined in.
**note that static functions only accept static variables Within themselves.**
now for example if you have defined this (following code) inside the `Main` class

```
public static var myGlobalVariable:*;
```

to gain access to `myGlobalVariable`, simply use this from any where:

```
Main.myGlobalVariable;
```